# Посчитать кол-во элементов после элемента

Tags: php, html

Как быстренько посчитать кол-во `<a>` элементов после последнего элемента `<div>` со `Static text` до закрывающего тега `</div>` посредством php?

```
<div>
    <div class="example">Dynamic text</div>
    <a></a>
    <div class="example">Dynamic text</div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <div class="example">Static text</div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Решение можно найти изощрениями, но задача какая-то... странная. Зачем это?

Comment: Для интеллектуального развития, скажем так :)

Comment: Тогда ищи через `strripos` нужный текст, от этой точки начинай считать количество элементов `<a></a>`. Парсить тут, думаю, не нужно.

Comment: Можно подробнее? `strripos` возвращает последнюю найденную позицию, чем мне это поможет? Не поймал ход Ваших мыслей.

Comment: Ищешь последнее вхождение `Static text`, от этой точки можешь считать остаются только те `<a></a>`, которые тебе нужны для подсчёта.

Comment: Все равно не понимаю, с помощью чего лучше искать дальше? Я до этого активно использовал `DOMElement` считывая дочерние элементы, и вот тут такой случай попался...

Comment: для этого лучше подходит javasrcipt,  например с помощью jquery можно на раз-два это посчитать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
$in = '
<div>
    <div class="example">Dynamic text</div>
    <a></a>
    <div class="example">Dynamic text</div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <div class="example">Static text</div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>';

var_dump(substr_count(substr($in, strripos($in, 'Static text</div>')), '<a>')); // int(2)
```

Через [`strripos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strripos.php) получаем последнее вхождение `Static text` в `<div></div>`, вырезаем подстроку от вхождения до конца, полученное прогоняем через функцию [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr-count.php), которая возвращает количество вхождений `<a>`.
Разумеется, код содержит много дыр, например: Не будет найден `Static text`, тег ссылки может быть с атрибутами, невалидные теги и пр.
Но как основа - пойдёт.

Comment: `Не будет найден Static text, тег ссылки может быть с атрибутами, невалидные теги и пр.` Но количество тегов `<a>` будет возвращать корректно?

Comment: Если код будет как в примере - да, сам видишь что вернул верно.